# Can I use custom generic collections in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a dll with generic collection inside. Can I use it in Xamarin.iOS app?

```
public class ResourcePagination<T> : IEnumerable
{
    public T First()
    {
     ...
    }
    ...
}
var x = new ResourcePagination<BankAccount>();
```

BankAccount is class defined in my app.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Generics are fully supported.